# Oracle Insert Data into XML Type Table

Tags: php, xml, oracle, codeigniter

I have a table with a XMLTYPE column, and i want to insert data into it in XML Format, but the information does not come in XML format from the server. I was thinking about implementing a stored procedure who takes the values from the server and Inserts the data in the XML Format into that column, but the procedure is giving me the right parenthesis error and i have no idea why.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE xml_tab (
id       NUMBER,
xml_data XMLTYPE
);
ALTER TABLE XML_TAB
MODIFY (ID DEFAULT XML_TAB_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
```

And the stored procedure that i'm trying to implement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_xml_proc (
dish_name IN VARCHAR,
dish_type IN VARCHAR,
dish_image IN VARCHAR ) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO XML_TAB (XML_DATA) values(
xmltype(
'<xml>
<item>
    <DISH_ID>'XML_TAB_SEQ.CURRVAL'</DISH_ID>
    <DISH_NAME>'dish_name'</DISH_NAME>
    <DISH_TYPE>'dish_type'</DISH_TYPE>
    <DISH_IMAGE>'dish_image'</DISH_IMAGE>
</item></xml>' ));
END;
```

The idea is that i use my form in PHP to send some variables into a stored procedure to insert this data. Inserting into a regular table and then fetching the data from it to insert as XML into the XML Table would also work, but the problem remains the same.

Thank you !

EDIT: The procedure v2 doesn't work because of the alias.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_xml_v2_proc (
dish_name IN VARCHAR2,
dish_type IN VARCHAR2,
dish_image IN VARCHAR2 ) AS
BEGIN
insert into xml_tab (xml_data) select xmlelement("xml", xmlelement("item",
                                xmlforest(XML_TAB_SEQ.nextval as dish_id,
                                          dish_name,
                                          dish_type,
                                          dish_image))) xmldata from dual;
END;
 /
```

Comment: What's the exact error message that you get, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not concatenating properly. It should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_xml_proc (
dish_name IN VARCHAR2,
dish_type IN VARCHAR2,
dish_image IN VARCHAR2 ) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO XML_TAB (XML_DATA) values(
xmltype(
'<xml>
<item>
    <DISH_ID>'||XML_TAB_SEQ.CURRVAL||'</DISH_ID>
    <DISH_NAME>'||dish_name||'</DISH_NAME>
    <DISH_TYPE>'||dish_type||'</DISH_TYPE>
    <DISH_IMAGE>'||dish_image||'</DISH_IMAGE>
</item></xml>' ));
END;
/
```

N.B. Note also that I've converted your parameters from `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR2`

There are better ways of generating xml, though, e.g.:

```
with sample_data as (select 'a' dish_name, 'b' dish_type, 'c' dish_image from dual)
select xmlelement("xml", xmlelement("item",
                                    xmlforest(XML_TAB_SEQ.nextval as dish_id,
                                              dish_name,
                                              dish_type,
                                              dish_image))) xmldata
from  sample_data;

XMLDATA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<xml><item><DISH_ID>262</DISH_ID><DISH_NAME>a</DISH_NAME><DISH_TYPE>b</DISH_TYPE><DISH_IMAGE>c</DISH_IMAGE></item></xml>
```

Comment: There are better ways of generating XML from columns/parameters - I've added one example into my answer

Comment: Is it possible to include that second way of generating xml into the procedure inside the insert statement?

Comment: you could convert that `insert ... values ...` into an insert as select, and just throw a `select ... from dual` around the outer `xmlelement(...)` part. E.g. `insert into xml_tab (xml_data) select xmlelement "xml", xmlelement(....)) xmldata from dual;`

Comment: Yeah, i will do that, looks more elegant. Thank you for this !

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're storing this in a table as xml; wouldn't it make more sense to store the values being passed in as columns in a table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116496/discussion-between-ribeiro-and-boneist).

Comment: I can't, sorry; I don't have access

Comment: Yeah it would make more sense, but my teacher insists on XML stored in the database. And since i am not able to store the documents directly in the server this is the second best approach.

Comment: Are you going to be querying stuff in the xml documents in the database? Or is the database simply a store for the documents? If the former, I would store the individual items in columns as well as the xml document. So, in borrowing your example, the xml_tab table would have columns dish_id, dish_name, dish_type and dish_image and xml_data.

Comment: I get your point of view, but i already have a view with the data parsed from XML_Tab so i can select it without a problem. The next big issue will be updating the XML record, but i guess i will just make it like the insert. The thing is, i have two tables. Dishes with the standart columns, and this one with ID and xml_type columns, and when i insert, i insert in both ( for now ) because once i have the CRUD working i will only use the XML_TAB.

Comment: The reason why I suggest you store the base data in columns as well as the xml doc is because, although you can certainly extract the information from the xml document, it's going to be slower than just pulling the information directly back from the table cols. If you're going frequently read the xml doc and pull out the base info, overall it's going to save you time and the database/server cpu overhead if you just read from the columns instead. Of course, if you're going to mainly pass the xml doc off outside of the db and not query it in the db, then maybe you don't need the separate cols.

Comment: P.s. for the updating of the xml, see [`updatexml`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions225.htm#SQLRF06172)

Comment: Thanks for the update thing. The second procedure is not working properly, compiles fine but then gives me an error about an alias, but i have the alias there. I updated the question with the code for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this (not tested)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_xml_proc (
dish_name IN VARCHAR,
dish_type IN VARCHAR,
dish_image IN VARCHAR ) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO XML_TAB (XML_DATA) values (
xmlelement("xml", 
   xmlelement("item", 
      xmlelement("DISH_ID", XML_TAB_SEQ.CURRVAL),
      xmlelement("DISH_NAME", dish_name),
      xmlelement("DISH_TYPE", dish_type),
      xmlelement("DISH_IMAGE", dish_image)
   )
)
);
```

Another way is like this one:

```
create or replace type "item" as object (
"DISH_ID" number,
"DISH_NAME" varchar2(100),
"DISH_TYPE" varchar2(100),
"DISH_IMAGE" varchar2(100));

INSERT INTO XML_TAB (XML_DATA) values (
xmlelement("xml", 
   xmltype("item"(XML_TAB_SEQ.CURRVAL, dish_name, dish_type, dish_image))
   )
);
```

or (however here I am not sure whether it is correct):

```
create or replace type "item" as object (
"DISH_ID" number,
"DISH_NAME" varchar2(100),
"DISH_TYPE" varchar2(100),
"DISH_IMAGE" varchar2(100));

create or replace type "xml" as object (
"item" "item");

INSERT INTO XML_TAB (XML_DATA) values (
xmltype("xml"(
    "item"(XML_TAB_SEQ.CURRVAL, dish_name, dish_type, dish_image))
   )
);
```

Comment: The first one works like a charm, not tested the next two. The only thing is that you need the END in the code. Thanks